# How to use django-siteflags to bookmark site objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models

The package is [here](https://django-siteflags.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-siteflags/) but I cannot get it to work.

Here is my **models.py** file

```
class Video(models.Model, ModelWithFlag):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    file = models.FileField(upload_to="static/videos/", null=True, verbose_name="", unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the views.py file

```
def user_bookmarked_video(request, bookmark_id):
    video = get_object_or_404(Video, pk=bookmark_id)
    # Now a user adds this article to his bookmarks.

    video.set_flag(request.user)
```

How should the **urls.py** and **.html** look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most of the question is not related to **siteflags** itself.

See "[Writing more views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views)" to have an example of **urls.py**.
For example, it might look like

```
path('videos/<int:bookmark_id>/', views.user_bookmarked_video, name='videos_bookmarked'),
```

However your **bookmark_id** is missleading, since it's a video ID, not a bookmark ID. Moreover your view is named **user_bookmarked_video()**, but it's not what it does — it just sets a flag (bookmark) on some video object.

If you plan to use this view just to set a bookmark you'd better name it like **set_video_bookmark()** and redirect at the end of the function, instead of html rendering.

If your intention was to show all bookmarked videos for current user then there's no need to accept **bookmark_id** argument for your view and flagging on every view call.

Your **html** may look like as you want, depending on what do you want to see.
For example:

```
<h1>{{ video.name }}</h1>
```

Comment: you are absoultey correct, it is not related to siteflags. But I could not find a single example of siteflags on the internet utilizing the package fully. Therefore, it would have been cool to see one fully working example from A to Z showing your hard-work floirsh :) Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Matthew I see. Since **siteflags** is generic you may use it in different scenarios. If you describe what do you want to achieve, we could improve the app docs with useful examples.

Comment: can you please check the `views.py`, I cannpt seem to remove or set the flag correctly.

Comment: Please do not edit your questions, if such edits change them in a substantial way, making the answers not relevant. If you have questions use the issue you've created — https://github.com/idlesign/django-siteflags/issues/5, not SO.

I've updated the docs, hope it'll help: https://django-siteflags.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: my apologies, I will roll back the question and post on the Github instead.